# React - How do a I set the Dropdown Menu state onChange()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to bind the onChange event of the dropdown menu to set the value to the selection. At the moment I can pass a reference to call handleChange. However since I don't know how to bind the dropdownmenu object to the this. I can't access this.state

Maybe my code structure need to shift to something like the demo: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu

However, if i do that, how would I pass in documentList?

So confused.
Gratefully appreciate a little support.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, Alert, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu'


const handleChange = (event, index, value) =>
{
console.log("handle change (value) ", value);
console.log("handle change (event) ", event);
console.log("handle change (index) ", index);

//How do i set the state of the dropdown object?


}

export const widget = ({ documentList }) => (
documentList.length > 0 ? <Paper style={{ paddingTop: 16,
        paddingBottom: 16,
        marginTop: 3,
        }}>
                            <form style={{ padding: 30 }} className="add-update-form" onSubmit={() => false}>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col md={2}>
                                        <DropDownMenu value={2} onChange={handleChange} openImmediately={true}>
                                            <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Starter" />
                                            <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Mains" />
                                            <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Drinks" />
                                        </DropDownMenu>
                                    </Col>
          </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

The component that you wrote is a stateless functional component, which is supposed to work just like a normal function. There is no state object in this case. You will need a class constructor in order to have access to the state object in your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, Alert, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';


class Widget extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

handleChange(event, index, value) {
  console.log("handle change (value) ", value);
  console.log("handle change (event) ", event);
  console.log("handle change (index) ", index);
  //Set States

}

render() {
   const documentList = this.props.documentList;
   //ES6 object destructing
   // const { documentList } = this.props;
  return() {
    if(!documentList.length > 0) return;
    <div>
     <Paper style={{ paddingTop: 16,
        paddingBottom: 16,
        marginTop: 3,
        }}>
      <form style={{ padding: 30 }} className="add-update-form" onSubmit={() => false}>
          <Row>
              <Col md={2}>
                  <DropDownMenu value={2} onChange={handleChange} openImmediately={true}>
                      <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Starter" />
                      <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Mains" />
                      <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Drinks" />
                  </DropDownMenu>
              </Col>
          </Row>
    </div>
  }
}
}

export default Widget;
```

---

This is the current version of Widget.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, Alert, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu'
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';





class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleChange(event, index, value) {
        console.log("handle change (value) ", value);
        console.log("handle change (event) ", event);
        console.log("handle change (index) ", index);
        //Set States
    }

    styles = {
        block: {
            maxWidth: 250,
        },
        toggle: {
            marginBottom: 16,
        },
        thumbOff: {
            backgroundColor: '#ffcccc',
        },
        trackOff: {
            backgroundColor: '#ff9d9d',
        },
        thumbSwitched: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        trackSwitched: {
            backgroundColor: '#ff9d9d',
        },
        labelStyle: {
            color: 'red',
        },
        customWidth: {
            width: 200,
        },
    };


    render() {
        const documentList = this.props.documentList;
        return () => {
            documentList.length > 0 ?
                <Paper style={{
                    paddingTop: 16,
                    paddingBottom: 16,
                    marginTop: 3,
                }}>
                    <form style={{padding: 30}} className="add-update-form" onSubmit={() => false}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col md={2}>
<DropDownMenu value={2} onChange={this.handleChange} openImmediately={true}>
                          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Starter" />
                          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Mains" />
                          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Drinks" />
                      </DropDownMenu>
                            </Col>
                            <Col md={2}>
                                <Toggle
                                    label="Dessert"
                                    labelPosition="right"
                                    style={this.styles.toggle}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <RaisedButton label="Save" primary={true} style={{marginRight: 15, marginTop: 15}} onClick=""/>
                    </form>
                </Paper> :
                <Alert bsStyle="warning">No stuff yet.</Alert>
        }

    }
}



Widget.propTypes = {
    documentList: React.PropTypes.array,
};

export default Widget;
```

Comment: I get this conceptually. Though this code does not work. Even after add back in the missing end tags for form and Paper. Ends of with a blank site and this error: Should provide a child component to build the higher order container

Comment: I hope you have a good understanding of what you are doing. This should solve your setState issue. You import this component in the container component and it should work just fine unless you are doing something wrong

Comment: Uncaught Error: Should provide a child component to build the higher order container.  Trying to figure that... I'm sure i'm doing something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Updated the code including some minor changes to the answer you recommended.

Comment: Does it work now after your changes or are you still facing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got a clue why, but managed to get the pages to render. So though i would share the solution..... I think it's soomething to do with prp types and maybe the version of reat i'm using...  "react": "^15.6.1", might upgrade later when i get a moment and see what happens. However the page renders so I am happy. Just need to fix the event handling.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, Alert, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu'
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';





export class OrderWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            toggle: true,
        },

            this.styles = {
                block: {
                    maxWidth: 250,
                }
                ,
                toggle: {
                    marginBottom: 16,
                }
                ,
                thumbOff: {
                    backgroundColor: '#ffcccc',
                }
                ,
                trackOff: {
                    backgroundColor: '#ff9d9d',
                }
                ,
                thumbSwitched: {
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                }
                ,
                trackSwitched: {
                    backgroundColor: '#ff9d9d',
                }
                ,
                labelStyle: {
                    color: 'red',
                }
                ,
                customWidth: {
                    width: 200,
                }
                ,
            }

    }


    handleChange(event, index, value) {
        console.log("handle change (value) ", value);
        console.log("handle change (event) ", event);
        console.log("handle change (index) ", index);
        //Set States

        this.state.setValue(value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Paper style={{
                paddingTop: 16,
                paddingBottom: 16,
                marginTop: 3,
            }}>
                <form style={{padding: 30}} className="add-update-form" onSubmit={() => false}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={2}>
                            <DropDownMenu value={2} onChange={this.handleChange} openImmediately={true}>
                                        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Starter" />
                          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Mains" />
                          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Drinks" />
                            </DropDownMenu>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={8}>
                            <TextField floatingLabelText="Units" hintText="Units" name="Units" ref="Units"
                                       key="Units" defaultValue="" fullWidth={false}/>
                            <TextField floatingLabelText="Price" hintText="Price" name="Price" ref="Price"
                                       key="Price" defaultValue="" fullWidth={false}/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={2}>
                            <Toggle
                                label="Side"
                                labelPosition="right"
                                style={this.styles.toggle}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <RaisedButton label="Save" primary={true} style={{marginRight: 15, marginTop: 15}}
                                  onClick=""/>
                </form>
            </Paper>


        );

    }

}

/*
Widget.propTypes = {
    documentList: React.PropTypes.array,
};
*/
```

Comment: strangely, i can't access this from inside handleChange